# Install Mosh on Almalinux 9

Tags: mosh, almalinux

I don't find the mosh-package for Almalinux 9. I have installed the EPEL as well as REMI repo. I have even tried to install from source, but get the error `C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check`. Anyone who has information about how to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the error message was due to lack of c++ compiler. When installed, the build managed.